# Java using builder with common fields

Tags: java, java-8, builder

I have a class Book with a builder. I have those methods below which seems to be contained in each other. 
I am wondering is there a more convenient way to use this builder. I cannot change the builder.

```
public static void tag(String type, String name, String id, String title, String genre, String author) {
Book.builder()
        .type(type)
        .name(name)
        .status(STATUS)
        .addTag(ID, id)
        .addTag(TITLE, title)
        .addTag(GENRE, genre)
        .addTag(AUTHOR, author)
        .build();
 }

public static void tag(String type, String name, String id, String author) {
    Book.builder()
            .type(type)
            .name(name)
            .status(STATUS)
            .addTag(ID, id)
            .addTag(AUTHOR, author)
            .build();
}

public static void tag(String type, String name) {
    Book.builder()
            .type(type)
            .name(name)
            .status(STATUS)
            .build();
}

public static void tag(String type, String name, Details details) {
    Book.builder()
            .type(type)
            .name(name)
            .status(STATUS)
            .addTag(JOB_ID, details.getJobId())
            .addTag(PROVIDER, details.getProvider())
            .addTag(LOCALE, details.getLocale())
            .build();
}

public static void tag(String type, String name, Details details, String id, String title, String genre, String author) {
    Book.builder()
            .type(type)
            .name(name)
            .status(STATUS)
            .addTag(JOB_ID, details.getJobId())
            .addTag(PROVIDER, details.getProvider())
            .addTag(LOCALE, details.getLocale())
            .addTag(ID, id)
            .addTag(TITLE, title)
            .addTag(GENRE, genre)
            .addTag(AUTHOR, author)
            .build();
}
```

Thanks for your ideas

Comment: What functionality are you trying to achieve that the above code doesn't do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming standard builder notation: https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern)

Currently, your methods do not return anything. This means that you create objects and instantly discard them (unless `.build()` persists them to some database, for example, but this is unusual and bad practice).

Also, you are repeating a lot of code. While this is more excusable when working with builders, it is still best to eliminate. A good way of removing the duplication is by having some methods return incomplete builders, and adding to them. For example:

```
public static BookBuilder tagBuilder(String type, String name, String id, String author) {
     return tagBuilder(type, name)
            .status(STATUS)
            .addTag(ID, id)
            .addTag(AUTHOR, author);
}

public static BookBuilder tagBuilder(String type, String name) {
    return Book.builder()
            .type(type)
            .name(name);
}
```

and when you want to create the book, just call:

```
Book book = tagBuilder("hello", "world", "foo", "bar").build();
```

However, I would ask why you need these classes. Why not just use the builder in the code that would otherwise call `tag()`. One of the main reasons builders are preferred over long, heavily overloaded methods is readability.

For example, the following code is not very readable - it is hard to know what it does:

```
CustomType customObj = new CustomType("abc 123", 7, 4);
```

Compare this to:

```
CustomType customObj = CustomTypeBuilder.builder()
   .setLicensePlate("abc, 123")
   .setAge(7)
   .setWheelCount(4)
   .build();
```

I have not changed the name of the class or object, but it is suddenly clear that this represents a vehicle.

Similarly, does `tag("novel", "Barack Obama", "id123", "George Bush")` refer to a book written by Barack Obama about George Bush, or the other way round? The only way of determining this is by reading the parameter names of `tag`, or reading the sources/javadocs, none of which may be available (you can also decompile for more reliable understanding of parameter values, but this is better to avoid).

Compare this to:

```
Book book = BookBuilder.builder()
    .setTitle("Barack Obama")
    .setType("novel")
    .setId("id123")
    .setAuthor("George Bush")
    .build();
```

You can probably get away with just using your builder wherever you would call `tag()`.

Comment: In other words, these overloaded static factory methods are (re)introducing all the problems, the builder initially solved.

Comment: because the builder is too long , I thought written it in a separate class will clean the code.

Comment: You will find that a long builder method, although it occupies more space on the screen, will be easier to understand 6 months in the future. If long lines are an issue, you can format as I have in my answer, with each builder call on a new line. At a more fundamental level, if you have, for example, 7 properties you want to set, you are going to have to provide 7 variables as parameters to **something**. I would argue a builder, although occupying more space, is more meaningful and less prone to typo errors